# Get a count of references for an object

Tags: c#, reference

I wanted to verify whether there is a way to get a count of references for a given object at runtime? I don't need to know exactly what is referencing it, just a number.

Comment: Do you mean programmatically or in the debugger? If debugger, which one?

Comment: programmatically during runtime, not via debugger.